# I have a function then a if else statement then a return with a maths in it

Tags: javascript, html

```
// var
var differentBillsInUSD;

// start of bills
differentBillsInUSD = {
    firstBill: parseInt(124),
    secondBill: parseInt(48),
    thirdBill: parseInt(268),
    fourthBill: parseInt(180),
    fifthBill: parseInt(42),
}

// console to check if everything is alright
console.log(differentBillsInUSD);
console.log("Checking if bill is alright ^");

function calcBill(numberBill) {
    if (numberBill < 50) {
        return(numberBill + " tip is: " (numberBill*0.20));
    } else if (numberBill >= 50 && numberBill <= 200) {
        return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " (numberBill*0.15));
    } else if (numberBill > 200) {
        return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " (numberBill*0.20));
    }
}
function calcBillTotal(numberBill) {
    if (numberBill < 50) {
        return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " ((numberBill*0.20)+numberBill));
    } else if (numberBill >= 50 && numberBill <= 200) {
        return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " ((numberBill*0.15)+numberBill));
    } else if (numberBill > 200) {
        return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " ((numberBill*0.20)+numberBill));
    }
}

// first bill
console.log(calcBill(differentBillsInUSD.firstBill));
console.log(calcBillTotal(differentBillsInUSD.firstBill));

// second bill
cosnole.log(calcBill(differentBillsInUSD.secondBill));
cosnole.log(calcBillTotal(differentBillsInUSD.secondBill));
ERROR CODE
script.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: " tip + total is: " is not a function
    at calcBill (script.js:21)
    at script.js:37
```

It won't work because I am doing to a coding challenge.
It also seems that I am new to javascript.
I tried to do my research, it was very difucult to find.
I am in the middle of code but can not fix.

Comment: Try adding space in between change `return(` to `return (`. Also the + operator you forgot. That's what error is trying to convey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return(numberBill + " tip is: "  **`+`** (numberBill*0.20));

you just miss to place a plus sign inside...

Answer (score 0):

return(numberBill + " tip + total is: " (numberBill*0.15));

In JS when you place () after anything it tries to execute it as a function. as you missed the "+" just before "(numberBill*0.15)", so its trying to execute " tip + total is: " as a function. You just need to add a "+"

Answer (score 0):

when you are concatenating a string with a variable , you need to use "+" sign in javascript. Here if you noticed in each if ,else if and else statement you are missing "+" sign.

if (numberBill < 50) {
        return(numberBill + " tip is: " **+** (numberBill*0.20));